# Flatten Parent/ Child Hierarchy in pyspark - dynamic

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, parent-child, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to flatten my  Parent/ Child Hierarchy dataset in pyspark.

This is my sample dataset  -

| Child | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| VP | CEO |
| Manager | VP |
| Senior | Manager |

I want my output in the following format in pyspark -

| Level | Path 1 | Path 2 | Path 3 | Path 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CEO | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | CEO | VP | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | CEO | VP | Manager | NULL |
| 3 | CEO | VP | Manager | Senior |

Many of the solutions I came across make use of parent_id to flatten the Hierarchies, which I do not have in my sample dataset.

**Note**- Path 5 column should be created dynamically if a new child is added in the dataset.
for example - Analyst reports to Senior and a new column should be dynamically created as shown -

| Level | Path 1 | Path 2 | Path 3 | Path 4 | Path 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | CEO | VP | Manager | Senior | Analyst |

I have tried as per this link, but this one makes use of parent_id to flatten.

[Flatten hierarchy table using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64401372/flatten-hierarchy-table-using-pyspark)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: I have mentioned the output above, please check thanks